QuestDB replication on schedule rather than real-time?
Is there any way to schedule updates on replicas instead of them happening automatically?
We were wondering if/how we could keep the resources necessary for the replicas at a minimum. So our idea would be to only update during the night, when load is low. Then during the day we have all resources available for queries with stale data.

QuestDB replication is meant to be in real-time, or at least as much in real-time as hardware, network, and object store allow.
There are some configuration parameters that can be fine tuned to assign fewer resources to the writing process and to reduce bandwidth usage.
Specifically you can limit:
native.async.io.threads=1
native.max.blocking.threads=4 replication.primary.compression.threads=4

You could also lower the concurrent uploads to a smaller number:
replication.requests.max.concurrent=4

This would slow down replication's activity.
For starters, I suggest initially to just following the tuning guide and leaving the rest as-is.
cairo.wal.segment.rollover.size=262144
replication.primary.throttle.window.duration=60000
replication.primary.sequencer.part.txn.count=1000

The main parameter here is replication.primary.throttle.window.duration=60000. you bump this up to more than a minute, e.g. add a zero for 10 minutes acceptable replication latency.
